# Bingbot is creating more sessions on my website than any other IP address

Tags: session, bingbot

I ran some aggregation on my site's session data, mostly out of curiosity.

I discovered that certain IP addresses had thousands of sessions, and as far as I can tell all of them were "open once, don't bother using again".

Of course, these are purged every so often by the garbage collector, but it seems like an awful lot.

Take Bingbot for example. Across a small number of IP addresses, there are no fewer than 100,000 opened sessions. That accounts for just about 15-20% of the total current number of sessions, all by itself.

I honestly expected that "rank" to go to some malicious user somewhere. Not Bingbot.

Is this normal, and what steps can I take to fix this if not? At the very least it would help if Bingbot actually used session cookies...

Comment: No search engine bot uses cookies between requests.   They want to see the page as a fresh user visiting your site from the search results would see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal to see abnormal bot behavior, in the sense that numbers do not seem to make sense. The boards are full of questions addressing many variations of similar situations.

**2 things to do if you have not done one, the other or both.**

1. Sign up with Bing webmaster tools: http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster
2. Control how Bing crawls your site: https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/crawl-control-55a30302

**Crawl Control** -
The Crawl Control feature in the Configure My Site Section allows you to exert control over the speed at which Bingbot makes requests for pages and resources on your website. You can tell Bingbot to crawl your site faster or slower than the normal crawl rate for each of the 24 hours in the day. This way you can to limit Bingbot activity when your visitors are on your site and allow us more bandwidth during quieter hours.